# Is there any way to use MCP4725 DAC with pymata4?

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

I'm using a MCP4725 DAC, an Arduino MEGA with a FirmataExpress sketch and the Pymata4 library in Python.

I want to change the value of the output voltage, but no matter what I give as arg, I always get 2.5V on the DAC output.

My code:

```cpp
def i2c_handle():
    board.set_pin_mode_i2c()
    board.i2c_write(0x62, [0xFFF])
```

Is there any way that I can use that DAC with Pymata4?

Comment: # No Clue Response
Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this problem.
For the DAC to work we have to pass to i2c_write() arddress and 3bytes of data. For example for 5V on the output:

```
    board.i2c_write(0x60, [64, 0b11111111, 0b11110000])
```

0x60 - adress of DAC

64 - cmd to update the DAC

0b11111111, 0b11110000 - binary equivalent of 4095 (5V), where the last 4 digits (0000) do not matter